# Как использовать переопределение оператора << внутри класса?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class basic
{
private:
  int x;
public:
  basic() { x = 0; }

  // можно ли изменить (необходимо cout << object), оставив внутри класса?:
  ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream)
  {
    stream << this->x << '\n';
    return stream;
  }
};

void code()
{
  basic obj;
  obj << cout; // работает, но нужно реализовать cout << obj;
}

int main() { code(); return 0;}
```

Comment: Что значит "внутри класса"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для этого вашему классу нужны друзья. Когда вы делаете так:

```
std::cout << obj;
```

Компилятору нужна соответствующая функция, чтобы подставить ее на это место. Как она может выглядеть? Ну навернякак как-то так:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, some_obj &);
```

====================================================

UPD:

```
если бы речь шла о том, как эта функция бы выглядела, если бы ее можно было засунуть прямо в `ostream`, то это было бы просто:

std::ostream &operator<<(some_obj &);
```

Так как первый параметр в методе класса и так является `this`, просто он там по умолчанию и скрыт от нас. Но мы не можем так сделать, можем только определить функцию за пределами класса, а раз так, то нужно самому передать то, что в методе передовалось бы по умолчанию, тобишь `this`.

===========================================================

Но, как видите, это не метод класса (да и не может им быть), так что не может обращаться к приватным переменным класса. Для того, чтобы мог - нужно объявить эту функцию внутри класса как friend:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, some_obj &);
```

Как-то так.

PS совсем забыл имя функции указать))

Answer (score 1):

```
# include <iostream>

class basic{
int x;
public:
friend std::ostream &  operator << ( std::ostream & , basic const & ) ;
};

std::ostream &  operator << ( std::ostream & s, basic const & me ) {
  s << (me.x);
  return s; }
```

Comment: Дополнение к ответу - функцию-друга можно определить прямо в классе, что +- похоже на "переопределить оператор << внутри класса", хоть на деле таковым не является.